# MySQL Order By not consistent

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a code in sql that tries to grab portfolios, share price  of some trades, in the numerical order by the trades.id field.

The problem is both values in the code below has to return in numerical order in order to calculate some type of allocation based on the weight.

However,

The return order of portfolios relative to trades.id field is the following

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6...
```

Return order of the "Weights" derived from "shares" is the following

```
1,2,3,4,5,6....0
```

They should both be in the order of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

PS. Not my code but i have to fix it in order for the application to work properly

```
SELECT 
    'O' AS Hint,
    GROUP_CONCAT(trades.id
        ORDER BY trades.id) AS ID,
    GROUP_CONCAT( (trades.Portfolio)
        ORDER BY trades.id) AS Portfolio,
    Ticker,
    Direction,
    FORMAT(SUM(Shares), 0) AS 'Shares',
    FORMAT(SUM(Shares), 0) AS 'Original Shares',
    Price,
    Broker AS Broker1,
    Commission,
    GROUP_CONCAT(FORMAT

    (trades.Shares/ 
    (SELECT SUM(Shares) FROM db.Trades WHERE id IN ('102370' , '102371','102372','102373','102374','102375','102376','102377','102380','102400')),12)) AS Weights,


    Issuer
FROM
    db.Trades
WHERE
    id IN ('102370' , '102371',
        '102372',
        '102373',
        '102374',
        '102375',
        '102376',
        '102377',
        '102380',
        '102400')
        AND is_deleted = '0'

GROUP BY Ticker , Direction , Price , Commission
ORDER BY trades.id
```

Comment: There are other issues with the query: You aggregate data and select `Broker`, but you don't group by it. This would raise an error in another DBMS, but MySQL converts this silently to `ANY_VALUE(Broker)`. This means a broker is arbitrarily picked from the group. If there are multiple brokers per group this may result in unexpected results. Single quotes delimit string literals, not names. So that should be `AS "Shares"` in Standard SQL and `AS \`Shares\` ` in MySQL. Numbers and strings should not be mixed. So it should probably be `id IN (102370 , 102371, …)` and `is_deleted = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed the bug.. The code was missing `order by trades.id` in the `group_concat` method that wraps the `shares`.

```
(trades.Shares/ 
       (SELECT SUM(Shares) 
             FROM db.Trades WHERE id IN 
 ('102370''102371','102372','102373','102374','102375','102376','102377','102380','102400')),12) 
 order by trades.id) AS Weights   -- <- here
```

Answer (score 0):

You query has this structure:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM . . .
GROUP BY Ticker , Direction , Price , Commission
ORDER BY trades.id
```

Note the `GROUP BY`.  After the `GROUP BY`, the only unaggregated columns are the ones listed:  `Ticker`, `Direction`, `Price`, and `Commission`.

Important question:  Does this list include `trades.id`?

In most databases (and the more recent versions of MySQL) you would get an error.  You can fix this using an aggregation function, say:

```
ORDER BY MIN(trades.id)
```

Comment: They already aggregate `trades.id` with a GROUP_CONCAT() AS ID, so they also could just `ORDER BY ID`.

Comment: I believe the problem is here `trades.Shares/ 
    (SELECT SUM(Shares) FROM db.Trades WHERE id IN ('102370' , '102371','102372','102373','102374','102375','102376','102377','102380','102400')),12)) AS Weights,`  Because when trades.shares is called, it returns in the order of, 1,2,3,4,5,6...0 when it actually should return 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: And to answer your question, yes they are all from the same table, trades

Comment: @Adas: You misunderstand what Gordon is trying to tell you. `trades.id` is not in your selected result, so you obviously cannot sort by it. You could only sort by an aggregation of it, e.g. `MIN(trades.id)`. Most DBMS would raise an exception. MySQL, however, translates silently to `ORDER BY ANY_VALUE(trades.id)`, i.e. it picks an ID arbitrarily from the group. This doesn't seem to make much sense. (This doesn't answer your original question, as your problem was the lack of `ORDER BY` in `GROUP_CONCAT`, but this is still worth considering when you are fixing the query anyway.)